# How to read data from a .usdc(pixar universal scene description) file via stream instead of a filepath?

Tags: c++, graphics, renderer, usd

I need to develop an usd asset parser for our renderer.
Now , i use the UsdStage::Open(std::string const& filepath) to get a UsdState and use it do something.
However, thirdparty library(i.e pixar usd) is not allowed to use the filepath directly in our render.
I now need to get stream data(i.e c++ istream) from our render's filesystem for use by the thirdparty library. For Alembec, i know it has an interface for c++ istream .But, i don't seem to see such an interface in pixar usd.

I also attempt to use the SdfLayer->ImportFromString(std::string const& str), but it doesn't seem to support the istream from .usdc format. And why does it print the parameters when it's called.